# No such element error when trying to get attribute of button tags

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the attribute of some button tags.

```
driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')

try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores'))
    )
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')
shopList = driver.find_element(By.ID, "shopList")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='shopList']/li/div/button"))
    )
    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()

print(shopList.get_attribute("class"))

li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

for item in li_items:
    
    first = item.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')
    second = first.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    coord = second.get_attribute("onclick")
    print(coord)
```

I am waiting for all of the button elements to load. However when I try to print the `onclick` attribute of all button tags it only prints the first two, then throws a "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element". But I could not figure out why. You can look at the html by going to "https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/" and choosing "Migros" from the rightmost dropdown. I kindly request your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibility_of_all_elements_located` will not really wait for **All** the elements matching the passed locator to become visible.
Actually, this method is similar to `visibility_of_element_located` method with only one difference: `visibility_of_element_located` returns a single web element while `visibility_of_all_elements_located` returns a list of web elements.
To achieve what you are looking for here, you can add a short delay of 1 second after applying the `visibility_of_all_elements_located` method to let all the web elements to be loaded.
Try this please:

```py
driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')

try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores')))
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')
shopList = driver.find_element(By.ID, "shopList")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='shopList']/li/div/button")))
    time.sleep(1)

    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()

print(shopList.get_attribute("class"))

li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

for item in li_items:
    
    first = item.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')
    second = first.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    coord = second.get_attribute("onclick")
    print(coord)
```

Comment: timeout exception in most cases indicates wrong locator.

Comment: It does not give timeout exception now, but still prints the first two attributes and can't locate the rest.

Comment: I see too much problems here...  first of all not all the `li` tag elements presenting the shops, each shop block contains 2 `//ul[@id='shopList']/li/div/button` elements, you will have to scroll the page in order to access the elements etc...

Comment: Do you know how I can scroll down while locating the elements?

Comment: Sure, but not while locating. You can get the list of elements and then scroll to each or any element in the list. But this is an additional question. I think I have answered your original question. If so please accept it and if you want to get helped with any other specific issue please open a new separate question per each specific problem.

Comment: You are welcome! Next time please write what is the problem exactly and give as much as possible details!